# Outputting text values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am unsure Excel would be able to do this automatically. I hope it can but maybe not.

I am trying to work with another member of staff in a different building. I have created a table trying to identify where the flow of some of the work is coming from. I am looking to try and count the amount of instances of text within a column. The problem is that the text can be pretty dynamic. As an example:

```
Consultant
a
a
b
a
b
a
b
z
c
c
c
```

Is there a way I can get excel to count the instances of text within the column, then create a table with the totals of the counts in it with labels.

I looked at pivot tables and that didn't seem to want to play ball.

Comment: Do you know which words or characters  (in your example a, b, c, and z) can occur?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We are trying to work out where the flow of work is coming from for a dept. I was hoping there would be a simple way of simply collecting the text data from excel, aggregating it then working from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is using COUINTIF

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"a")
```

Which will simply tell you how many times "a" appears in the Column A.
You could easily duplicate this for every letter of the alphabet.  Then use a summary table to display the results.

Comment: The a b c was simply a example. The problem is that we are trying to pin down which consultants are generating the most work for a dept. So the column could be filled with any number of different names. Not specifically in any kind of list.

Comment: You can still use that same trick.  Even if you are not looking for a single character.  You can replace that with a substring that matches a person's name.

Comment: Cheers. I have just been emailed a definitive list of the consultants. Thankfully it is not as bad as we thought. Thank you I will get to work on this.